# Is 2nd derivative RK4 method better than classic Runge-Kutta 4?

Tags: physics, runge-kutta-methods

We have a Newtonian physics simulation with a state matrix containing the instantaneous velocities, angular velocities, positions and orientations of an object ; and we apply classical Runge-Kutta 4 method to advance step by step in the simulation.

For now, at each step, we compute the new velocities and the new position/orientation at once multiplying our state-derivative matrix with RK4 timesteps and half-timesteps.

I was wondering if and why RK4 with 2nd-derivative would give more precise results. As we compute all necessary linear and angular accelerations in the process, we could easily switch to 2nd-derivative RK4.

I hope I gave enough details, I can give more if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the difference, RK4 is RK4, whatever way you organize the relevant linear operations. I assume in one variant you eliminate the updates of $\dot X=V$ like in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/solving-coupled-odes-using-runge-kutta-method/34330#34330?

Comment: I'm quite new to this method so I am not sure of the underlying difference. Indeed, in both cases we apply RK4, but with the 2nd derivative it is applied on a different set of equations I guess.
Sadly the two methods are only described on the french wikipedia page, couldn't find in on the english one: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thodes_de_Runge-Kutta#La_m%C3%A9thode_de_Runge-Kutta_d'ordre_quatre_avec_d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e_seconde

Comment: From what I understand,

RK4 on our 6-components state-vector: $X_{n+1}$ is computed from the derivative of $X_n$, and $V_{n+1}$ if computed from the derivative of $V_n$.

RK4 with 2nd derivative: acceleration is not only taken into account in $V_{n+1}$, but also in $X_{n+1}$, without having to wait for one more derivation step.

I'm not sure this is true, or if this even has an impact on the final result, though.

Comment: Yes, that is the same simplification as in my linked answer. It is just using the "triangular" structure of the first-order system to avoid some intermediate variables $P^k$ by directly using their expressions. There should not be any difference above that what a general theoretically equivalent re-ordering of arithmetic operations gives in floating point operations.

Comment: There are methods for second order equations that are really partitioned, that is, where position and velocity are treated separately. But mostly these are for special second order systems for molecular dynamics, celestial dynamics, general Hamiltonian mechanics. Energy dissipation will generally destroy the special properties of these methods, so that general methods for first-order systems will be more reliable to apply.